# 2d ball collisions

Tags: visual-c++

The collision detection with each ball in my bouncing ball program is done,
now got new problem for knowing the next event after the collision.
I got stuck for knowing the new velocity of the ball after hitting another ball.
I tried the method discussed [here](http://www.vobarian.com/collisions/2dcollisions2.pdf)

I implemented the algorithm and it doesn't work at all.
After the collision, the balls just got a velocities of zero.
I found out that the new value generated is less than 1.0e-13, which demoted by a float type to zero that I use for handling values of velocities and coordinates

I don't know if the method I use is not good for floating points or I just mistaken following those steps in my reference.
I'm not good at physics at all.

here is the code:

```
void Physics::Add(Ball object[]) {
    for (int i = 0;i < Ball::numOfObj; ++i){

        for(int j = 0;j < Ball::numOfObj; ++j){
            if(i == j) break;

            if(PotentialBallCollision(object[i], object[j])){
                Vector2f normalVector ( object[i].pos.X - object[j].pos.X,
                                    object[i].pos.Y - object[j].pos.Y);

                float resultant = _sqrt((normalVector.X * normalVector.X) +
                                    (normalVector.Y * normalVector.Y));

                Vector2f resultantVector (resultant, resultant);

                Vector2f unitNormal =   (normalVector / resultantVector);

                Vector2f unitTangent (-unitNormal.Y, unitNormal.X);

                float velN1 = (unitNormal.X * object[i].vel.X) * (unitNormal.Y * object[i].vel.Y);
                float velT1 = (unitTangent.X * object[i].vel.X) * (unitTangent.Y * object[i].vel.Y);
                float velN2 = (unitNormal.X * object[j].vel.X) * (unitNormal.Y * object[j].vel.Y);
                float velT2 = (unitTangent.X * object[j].vel.X) * (unitTangent.Y * object[j].vel.Y);
                velN1 = (velN1 * (object[i].mass - object[j].mass) + 2 * (object[j].mass * velN2)) /
                    (object[i].mass + object[j].mass);
                velN2 = (velN2 * (object[j].mass - object[i].mass) + 2 * (object[i].mass * velN1)) /
                    (object[i].mass + object[j].mass);

                velN1 *= unitNormal.X * unitNormal.Y;
                velT1 *= unitTangent.X * unitTangent.Y;
                velN2 *= unitNormal.X * unitNormal.Y;
                velT2 *= unitTangent.X * unitTangent.Y;

                float newVel1 = velN1 + velT1;
                float newVel2 = velN2 + velT2;

            /*object[i].vel = Vector2f(newVel1 , newVel1); //<-- this is the generated velocities
                object[j].vel = Vector2f(newVel2, newVel2);*/

                object[i].vel.X *= -1; //fake physics
                object[i].vel.Y *= -1; //
                object[j].vel.X *= -1; //
                object[j].vel.Y *= -1; //
            }

                if(PotentialWallCollision(object[j])){
                    switch(object[j].dir)
                    {
                    case Vector2f::UP:
                    case Vector2f::DOWN:
                        object[j].vel.Y *= -1;
                        break;
                    case Vector2f::LEFT:
                    case Vector2f::RIGHT:
                        object[j].vel.X *= -1;
                        break;
                     }
                }
                if(PotentialWallCollision(object[i])){
                    switch(object[i].dir)
                    {
                    case Vector2f::UP:
                    case Vector2f::DOWN:
                        object[i].vel.Y *= -1;
                        break;
                    case Vector2f::LEFT:
                    case Vector2f::RIGHT:
                        object[i].vel.X *= -1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    object[i].pos += object[i].vel;
                    object[j].pos += object[j].vel;
            }
    }
}
```

I'm suspicious that the problem is in the resultant vector which I made only by myself because I don't understand this formula-> `Vectors: unitNormal = normalVector / sqrt(normalVector.X ^ 2 + normalVector.Y ^ 2)`
so I made a new variable called resultant and make that value be the x and y of resultant vector just to divide it to another vector.

Comment: is this a question, or an answer?

Comment: it's a question. anyway, I already figured out the problem there(I forgot to separate X and Y when getting the magnitude). now there's another problem, conservation of energy is lost and balls are clinging randomly with each other but others don't(maybe this is the reason why energy is lost). I thought of before changing it's velocity, I should make them apart a bit to avoid clinging but I don't know how to do it.